# every() some() and functions returning functions

Tags: javascript

I am working through NodeSchool's Functional Javascript course. The "Every Some" exercise provides a "goodUsers" array of objects argument to compare another list of users to (also an array of objects).

I was hoping if someone could help me visualize what is going on in the solution:

```
function checkUsersValid(goodUsers) {
  return function allUsersValid(submittedUsers) {
    return submittedUsers.every(function(submittedUser) {
      return goodUsers.some(function(goodUser) {
        return goodUser.id === submittedUser.id;
      });
    });
  };
}

module.exports = checkUsersValid;
```

These are the instructions provided:

```
# Task

Return a function that takes a list of valid users, and returns a function that returns true if all of the supplied users exist in the original list of users.

You only need to check that the ids match.

## Example

    var goodUsers = [
      { id: 1 },
      { id: 2 },
      { id: 3 }
    ]

    // `checkUsersValid` is the function you'll define
    var testAllValid = checkUsersValid(goodUsers)

    testAllValid([
      { id: 2 },
      { id: 1 }
    ])
    // => true

    testAllValid([
      { id: 2 },
      { id: 4 },
      { id: 1 }
    ])
    // => false

## Arguments

  * goodUsers: a list of valid users

Use array#some and Array#every to check every user passed to your returned function exists in the array passed to the exported function.
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly are you having issues understanding? Without a narrower focus this question is too broad.

Comment: This also seems to be a poor/useless code example.  Why would one want to iterate through these arrays of objects looking at every single combination (an O(n^2) complexity operation) when one could build a more appropriate data structure to store valid ID's for lookup.  Not too mention that level of nesting is just absurd to try to read - as you are noticing. I do agree that it is not clear from your question what you are asking.

Comment: It's probably written that way just to show people that it's possible. Hopefully they make it clear that you would split them out in real life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added annotations that briefly describe each functions purpose. I wouldn't solve the problem this way but none the less it explains what each part is doing

```
function checkUsersValid(goodUsers) {

  // allUsersValid is a function that compares lists of users against each other
  // if they do not match exactly return false if they do match return true 

  return function allUsersValid(submittedUsers) {

    // .every checks to see if every element in array passes a test
    // defined by the following function if every element passes
    // it will return true, and if not return false
    return submittedUsers.every(function(submittedUser) {

    // .some is a function that tests to see if any elements pass the
    // test defined by the function I.E. does this submitted user.id
    // match any of the goodUsers ids if so pass true else false
    // if all return true then .every returns true if any of them
    // return false then .every will return false
      return goodUsers.some(function(goodUser) {
        return goodUser.id === submittedUser.id;
      });
    });
  };
}

module.exports = checkUsersValid;
```

Answer (score 3):

`checkUsersValid`: function returns a function with goodUsers in the scope.

`allUsersValid`: returns true if all submittedUsers are contained in  goodUsers. goodUsers variable is available to the function via the original closure created by running `checkUsersValid`.

`submittedUsers.every` : runs callback on each element. Will return true if every callback invocation will return true.

`goodUsers.some` : runs callback on each element. Will return true if at least one invocation will return true.

`return goodUser.id === submittedUser.id` : goodUser is in the scope of the last callback. submittedUser in the parent scope.

In other words the returned function checks that all submitted users are contained in the good users. for that `every` submitted user needs to be referred at least once (`some`) in the good users.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments that this example is a little ridiculous, but we can still break down how it works.

The first function defined, `checkUsersValid`, takes an array of good users that you can check against in the future. The function that it returns, `allUsersValid`, will have access to `goodUsers` whenever it is invoked. This is an example of [partial application](http://benalman.com/news/2012/09/partial-application-in-javascript/), although I'm not sure I see the use for it in this scenario.

If we were to do it without partial application, it would probably look something like this:

```
function allUsersValid(goodUsers, submittedUsers) {
    return submittedUsers.every(function(submittedUser) {
        return goodUsers.some(function(goodUser) {
            return goodUser.id === submittedUser.id;
        });
    });
}
```

Which you would call like this:

```
var goodUsers = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 }
];

allUsersValid( goodUsers, [
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 1 }
]);
```

Now, for how `allUsersValid` works: it uses [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to verify that each user in `submittedUsers` exists in `goodUsers`. `every` iterates over an array and returns true if the callback returns true for each element in the array. `some` is similar, except it will return true as long as the callback returns true for at least one element in the array. So, what happens is that it iterates over each user from `submittedUsers` and then - for each of those users - iterates over each user in `goodUsers` until it finds an ID that matches that matches the submitted user. If it does not find an ID for every submitted user, the function will return false.